# Ubuntu: wire network is not stable and must restart network-manager periodcally

Tags: linux, networking

I don't know why my wire network now is not stable. After a short time of using, maybe 30 minutes, 15 minutes or maybe just 2 minutes, my network is down. When my network is down, I must run this command two times:

```
service network-manager restart
```

First time, it just disconnect network. and at second time, it restarts the network and runs smoothly again. I don't know why and how to fix this. I'm using Ubuntu 13.04. Before that, I used Fedora 18, and still meet this problem.

Comment: What hardware do you have? Please try and be as specific as you can (i.e. model #'s, manufacturing info, etc).

Comment: If this is a laptop: does it happen only in one location, or everywhere? (If this is a desktop, try to connect it to a different network if you can.) Please post the log lines from `/var/log/syslog` that appear when you start the network, and the log lines when you lose the connection.

Comment: Cool thanks for the work around. My autocomplete didnt show network-manager, and restarting networking and doing `sudo NetworkManager start` wasnt helping.. Was rebooting the machine almost daily, or more often..

Answer (score 1):

This is a know bug in Ubuntu 13.04 kernels...
See [Ethernet connection not stable on Ubuntu 13.04(bug exists in 32bit and 64bit version) (kernel-bug-exists-upstream)](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1176370).